# UIStackView : Change UIStackView image width using storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode7, uistackview

The issue : Image take most of the stack and text shrinks

I tried to change content hugging priority but no changes !

How to do it in UIStackview using **storyboard**?

What I want the cell to look like Eventbright event Cell?
[image]
[image]

What I got is an image that take most of the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it the following way.
The overall set up is given in pic:

[image]

At run time result is as given:

[image]

- First Stack view is fill proportionally
- imageview width is 1:4 of stackview width (control and drag from imageview to stackview and set equal width to 25% )

From control and drag select equal width. as shown

[image]

[image]

- stack view 2 is fill equally
- stack view 3 is fill equally

Hope it can help

Comment: Where should I type 25% ?

Comment: When you control and drag from imageview to stack view select equal width. then go to size inspector and double click the constraint. you will see the above window show in answer. type 25% in Multiplier.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `Fill`, change the `Distribution` of the `UIStackView` to `Fill Proportionally` and add constraints for the width of each element. Those constraints will serve as a guide to proportions on one element to each other and not as fixed sizes.